# How to get gender of users attending some event (Facebook Graph API)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get gender of facebook users via Facebook Graph API, that are attending some event? Or just by users' ids?

Comment: What version is the app you're using? v2.0, or later?

Comment: Then you can't use FQL, which had a nice solution to your problem. @Noel's answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that way, but for some reason had no luck, can't access anything except name, id and link

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the `events/attending` endpoint:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/event/attending

Your request would be `/{TheEventId}/attending`
Which returns a list of `user` objects:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

...which looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "What What", 
      "rsvp_status": "attending", 
      "id": "10152412233197215"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "What What", 
      "rsvp_status": "attending", 
      "id": "1682602711966379"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "What What", 
      "rsvp_status": "attending", 
      "id": "10201675684423330"
    }
]
```

You would then need to use the user `id` to query for each user's details.  The user object has a `gender` field.

```
{
  "id": "10142215948176947", 
  "gender": "male", 
...
}
```

Also note the [permission limitations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference):

> gender & locale can only be accessed if:
>
> - The person queried is the person using the app.
> - The person queried is using the app, and is a friend of the person using the app.
> - The person queried is using the app, is not a friend of the person using    the app, but the app includes either an app access token or
>     an    appsecret_proof argument with the call

Comment: yes, I tried this way, but even if the user is my friend and is using the app I can't access anything except : first_name, id, last_name, link, name, updated_time.. any ideas?

Comment: If you can't see that info, it's likely a permissions issue

Comment: As I understand, for this I only need "public_profile" permission, and I checked - it was granted..